# AngularJS: Insert HTML into View from string preserving style attributes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to insert an HTML code from `string` into angular view, but all style attributes are being removed from the HTML

In the Controller:

```
$scope.htmlString = '<div style="height:40px;"></div><div style="height:40px;"></div><div style="height:40px;"></div>'
```

View:

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlString"></div>
```

The result I'm getting is always the HTML without style attributes.

```
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

I have tried using `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directive with no success.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: why are you even trying to store this kind of HTML in a variable in the first place?

Comment: @Claies this is only an example, that HTML is generated by a function and I need to insert it as is.

Comment: generated by a function still doesn't say much.  if it is an angular function, then there are many other better ways than this.  If it is generated by the server, that's a code smell of it's own, as the server shouldn't be responsible for controlling the client view.  also, there are better ways to get server content output than in a raw string variable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but @AliAdravi 's answer is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the [fidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AliAdravi/p021e2da/)

```
$scope.str = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
<div ng-bind-html="str"></div>
```